# Regular expression displaying search characters

Tags: regex, vb.net

The following vb statement in linqpad

```
Dim userAgent As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)"
 Dim pattern As String = "\(([^\]]+)\;"
 Dim regex As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern)
 Dim operatingSystem As Match = regex.Match(userAgent)
 operatingSystem.Value.Dump()
```

With an output of `(Windows NT 6.1;`

Is there a way with this regular expression to omit the `(` and `;` from the resulting match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look arounds would be usefull in such cases.

```
(?<=\()[^\]]+(?=;)
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pY8cA6/1)

The look around assertions doesn't consume any characters. Hence those `(` and `;` won't be there in the matched string.

Answer (score 1):

Simply access the first captured group:

```
operatingSystem.Groups(1).Value
```

And you can improve your pattern as follows:

```
Dim pattern As String = "\(([^;]+)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use look-arounds if you do not need to match, but only check presence of:

```
Dim userAgent As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)"
Dim pattern As String = "(?<=\()[^\]]+(?=;)"
Dim regex As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern)
Dim operatingSystem As Match = regex.Match(userAgent)
Dim resulting_value As String = operatingSystem.Value
```

[image]

**REGEX EXPANATION**:

- `(?<=\()` - A positive look-behind that checks for `(` right before...
- `[^\]]+` - 1 or more chracters other than a `]`...
- `(?=;)` - followed by a `;`.

Note in .NET, you do not even have to escape the `]` at the final position in the character class, so even `(?<=\()[^]]+(?=;)` will do.